# Query that will loop through a range of years

Tags: sql, loops, ms-access

I'm looking for a way to have an ACCESS query return results for a range of years.  Since there are aggregate calculations in the query, changing the BETWEEN statement to a range of years results in an error.  I could use UNION statements and repeat the code for each year but that isn't very efficient.  Can it be done with just SQL code or does VB have to be used.  I don't know VB so if the answer is that VB is needed I would appreciate detailed information.

The code for the ACCESS query is below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DatePart("yyyy",sale_date) AS [YEAR],

    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0) ,2) 
     FROM SALES_RECEIPT
     INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
     WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009#) AS [Gross Sales],

    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum((Nz(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE,0))*sales_receipt.quantity),0),2) 
     FROM SALES_RECEIPT
     INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
     WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009#) AS COGS,

    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0) - Nz(Sum(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0),2) 
     FROM INVENTORY 
     INNER JOIN SALES_RECEIPT ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
     WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009#) AS [Sales Margin],

    Round((((SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0) - Nz(Sum(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0),2) 
             FROM INVENTORY 
             INNER JOIN SALES_RECEIPT ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
             WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009# )
             /
            (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0),2) 
             FROM SALES_RECEIPT
             INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
             WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009#))*100),0) & "%" AS [Profit Margin],

    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * deductions_inventory.quantity), 0),2)
     FROM INVENTORY INNER JOIN DEDUCTIONS_INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = DEDUCTIONS_INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID
     WHERE DEDUCTIONS_INVENTORY.ENTRY_DATE Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009# ) AS [Inventory Deductions],

    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * DEDUCTIONS_EXPENSE.quantity), 0),2)
     FROM INVENTORY INNER JOIN DEDUCTIONS_EXPENSE ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = DEDUCTIONS_EXPENSE.INVENTORY_ID
     WHERE DEDUCTIONS_EXPENSE.ENTRY_DATE Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009# ) AS [Inventory Expenses], 

    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(DEDUCTIONS_FIXTURES_CHAINS.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE*DEDUCTIONS_FIXTURES_CHAINS.quantity),0),2) 
     FROM DEDUCTIONS_FIXTURES_CHAINS
     WHERE DEDUCTIONS_FIXTURES_CHAINS.ENTRY_DATE Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009# and REASON="Breakage-Theft") AS [Fixture & Chain Deductions], 

    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(DEDUCTIONS_FIXTURES_CHAINS.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE*DEDUCTIONS_FIXTURES_CHAINS.quantity),0),2) 
     FROM DEDUCTIONS_FIXTURES_CHAINS
     WHERE DEDUCTIONS_FIXTURES_CHAINS.ENTRY_DATE Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009# and REASON="Promotion") AS [Fixture & Chain Expenses], 

    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(returns.selling_price * returns.quantity), 0),2)
     FROM returns inner JOIN inventory ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = returns.INVENTORY_ID
     WHERE returns.return_date Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009# ) AS [Sales Returns], 

    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0) - Nz(Sum(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0),2)
     FROM INVENTORY 
     INNER JOIN SALES_RECEIPT ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
     WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009#)
     -
    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * deductions_inventory.quantity), 0),2)
     FROM INVENTORY INNER JOIN DEDUCTIONS_INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = DEDUCTIONS_INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID
     WHERE DEDUCTIONS_INVENTORY.ENTRY_DATE Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009#)
     -
    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * DEDUCTIONS_EXPENSE.quantity), 0),2)
     FROM INVENTORY INNER JOIN DEDUCTIONS_EXPENSE ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = DEDUCTIONS_EXPENSE.INVENTORY_ID
     WHERE DEDUCTIONS_EXPENSE.ENTRY_DATE Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009#)
     -
    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(DEDUCTIONS_FIXTURES_CHAINS.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE*DEDUCTIONS_FIXTURES_CHAINS.quantity),0),2) 
     FROM DEDUCTIONS_FIXTURES_CHAINS
     WHERE DEDUCTIONS_FIXTURES_CHAINS.ENTRY_DATE Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009#) 
     -
    (SELECT Nz(Sum(returns.selling_price * returns.quantity), 0)
     FROM returns inner JOIN inventory ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = returns.INVENTORY_ID
     WHERE returns.return_date Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009#) AS [Gross Profit]

FROM
    INVENTORY
    INNER JOIN SALES_RECEIPT ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
WHERE
    (((SALES_RECEIPT.SAle_date) Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009#))
GROUP BY
    DatePart("yyyy",sale_date);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle you need to replace all `Between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2009#` conditions in the subqueries with a condition correlated with the outer query.
If you do it as is, you will have an utterly inefficient query that will calculate totals for each individual record in the outer query.

You do not seem to be using the outer query for anything other than giving you the single year number (2009) in this case.

Therefore change the outer query to simply return the year numbers of interest, and make the subqueries correlated, e.g.

```
SELECT
    Year(years.year_start) AS [YEAR],

    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0) ,2) 
     FROM SALES_RECEIPT
     INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
     WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] between years.year_start and years.year_end) AS [Gross Sales],

    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum((Nz(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE,0))*sales_receipt.quantity),0),2) 
     FROM SALES_RECEIPT
     INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
     WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] between years.year_start and years.year_end) AS COGS,

    etc
FROM
    (select
         DateSerial(Year(sale_date), 1, 1) as year_start,
         DateSerial(Year(sale_date), 12, 31) as year_end
     from SALES_RECEIPT
     where sale_date between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2015#
     group by Year(sale_date)
    ) as years
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and is very efficient so I used this method.  Thank you so much for your answer!!

Comment: I have a very similar query that does the aggregate calculations monthly instead of yearly. Could your solution for yearly aggregate calculations be easily modified for monthly calculations through a range of years.  I have a new posting for this question.

Comment: Replace `group by Year(sale_date)` with `group by Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date)` and use `DateSerial(Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date), 1)` and `DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date) + 1, 1))` for begin-end dates for each month.

Comment: It works great!  There is a column that displays the month but not the year. How can I create a column to display the year? Or maybe both the month/year in the same column.  Thank you so much!

Comment: You are grouping by both `Year(sale_date)` and `Month(sale_date)`. What stops you from putting them both to the select list?

Comment: When try to add Year(sale_date) to the select list, I get the message box  "Enter Parameter Value  sale_date"  which indicates that the query is not recognizing any sale_date values from the SALES_RECEIPT table even though it looks like it should.                                                                    SELECT Year(sale_date) AS [YEAR], Month(months.month_start) AS [MONTH],

Comment: You don't have `sale_date` in the outside query. You should be using `Year(months.month_start) AS [YEAR], Month(months.month_start)`.

Comment: That solved the problem.  Thank you so much!  I would like to modify the query so it does daily calculations through a range of years but the modifications I tried didn't work.  The key changes I made are below and in the next comment.                                                                                         SELECT Year(days.day_start) AS [YEAR], 
Month(days.day_start) AS [MONTH], 
Day(days.day_start) AS [DAY],                                                                           WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] between days.day_start and days.day_end) AS [Gross Sales]

Comment: FROM (SELECT                                                             DateSerial(Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date), Day(sale_date, 1) AS day_start, 
DateAdd("d", -1,  DateSerial(Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date), Day(sale_date) + 1, 1)) AS day_end                                                     FROM SALES_RECEIPT WHERE sale_date between #1/1/2009# And #12/31/2016#                                                              
GROUP BY Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date), Day(sale_date)) AS days;

Comment: [Of course it does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5434001/11683). Why are you adding a day and subtracting it back immediately? You should subtract a second with that `DateAdd`, not a day. And why are providing four parameters to ` DateSerial` and two parameters to `Day`?

Comment: At which point it is obvious your `sale_date` also has a time component, in which case the query ignores sales that happened on the last day. You should then remove the `dateadd` and use `>=` and `<` instead of `between`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing the outer aggregate query's `WHERE` clause that filters for 2009 dates and have each subquery relate to distinct sale_date years. No need for the `BETWEEN` clauses but use `DatePart("yyyy", ...)` which will correspond to every distinct year in `SALES_RECIEPT` table. Below is the adjustment for first three subqueries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DatePart("yyyy", SALES_RECEIPT.sale_date) AS [YEAR],

    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sub1.SELLING_PRICE * sub1.quantity),0) ,2) 
     FROM SALES_RECEIPT AS sub1
     INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = sub1.INVENTORY_ID
     WHERE DatePart("yyyy", sub1.[SALE_DATE]) =  
           DatePart("yyyy", SALES_RECEIPT.sale_date)) As [Gross Sales],

    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum((Nz(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE,0)) * sub2.quantity),0),2) 
     FROM SALES_RECEIPT As sub2
     INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = sub2.INVENTORY_ID
     WHERE DatePart("yyyy", sub2.SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE]) = 
           DatePart("yyyy", SALES_RECEIPT.sale_date)) AS COGS,

    (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sub3.SELLING_PRICE * sub3.quantity),0) - 
            Nz(Sum(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * sub3.quantity),0),2) 
     FROM SALES_RECEIPT As sub3
     INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = sub3.INVENTORY_ID
     WHERE DatePart("yyyy", sub3.sale_date) =  
           DatePart("yyyy", SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE])) AS [Sales Margin],

    ...

FROM
    INVENTORY
    INNER JOIN SALES_RECEIPT ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
GROUP BY
    DatePart("yyyy", SALES_RECEIPT.sale_date);
```

Comment: Great! Please select either one of above answers to confirm resolution.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the DATEPART function to get the year of the date, like this 
WHere datepart ("y, fielddaye) <1999 and datepart (y, fieldate ) > 1990. Once it works you can even patamaterise the years.
Please note :
SUM aggregate NULL to 0, so you don't need NZ function on top of it 
HTH.