# Query that returns monthly aggregate calculations for a range of years

Tags: sql, loops, ms-access, aggregate-functions

I'm looking for a way to have an ACCESS query return monthly aggregate calculations for each month of the year for a range of years.

Right now I have the code below repeated for each month using a `UNION` statement but that isn't very efficient and I have to create a separate query for each year.

I recently asked a similar question about how to get a query return yearly aggregate calculations for a range of years and received 2 great solutions.  I tried modifying those solutions for months but I couldn't get it to work.

I would greatly appreciate a solution for monthly aggregate calculations.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Format(DatePart("m",sale_date),"00") & " / " & DatePart("yyyy",sale_date) AS [Month / Year], 

  (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0) ,2) 
    FROM SALES_RECEIPT
    INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
    WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] Between #1/1/2014# And #1/31/2014#) AS [Gross Sales], 

  (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum((Nz(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE,0))*sales_receipt.quantity),0),2) 
    FROM SALES_RECEIPT
    INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
    WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] Between #1/1/2014# And #1/31/2014#) AS COGS,

  (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0) - Nz(Sum(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0),2) 
    FROM INVENTORY 
    INNER JOIN SALES_RECEIPT ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
    WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] Between #1/1/2014# And #1/31/2014#) AS [Sales Margin]

FROM 
    INVENTORY INNER JOIN SALES_RECEIPT ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
    WHERE (((SALES_RECEIPT.SAle_date) Between #1/1/2014# And #1/31/2014#))
GROUP BY
    Format(DatePart("m",sale_date),"00") & " / " & DatePart("yyyy",sale_date)
```

Comment: First answers to your related [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610282/query-that-will-loop-through-a-range-of-years) both did not contain hard coded dates in each subquery as dates correlated to outer query. In fact, it looks like you reverted back to original setup where instead of 2009 you have 2014. Second, there is no `UNION` clause in posted query here.

Comment: I have this query functioning for months with the code repeated for each month by using UNION statements. It's basically the same as my yearly aggregate calculations query but done monthly instead of yearly.  Since it would have been a lot of code to post, I only included the first 3 columns for the month of January and did not post the other months.  I have numerous copies of this monthly query with a different years including 2009.  I tried modifying your answer for the yearly query to make it work for the monthly query but it didn't work so I posted the code from my original query.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to make a query to get your values and do your calculations, then enclose that in a subquery to aggregate from. Try this (untested):

```
SELECT a.[Sale Month], 
    a.[Sale Year],
    ROUND(SUM(a.[Gross Sales]),2) AS [Gross Sales],
    ROUND(SUM(a.[COGS]),2) AS [COGS],
    ROUND(SUM(a.[Sales Margin]),2) AS [Sales Margin],
    Round((Sum(a.[Sales Margin])/Sum([Gross Sales]))/100,2) AS [Profit Margin]
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        Format(DatePart("m",s.sale_date),"00") AS [Sale Month], 
        DatePart("yyyy",s.sale_date) AS [Sale Year], 
        Nz(s.SELLING_PRICE * s.quantity,0) AS [Gross Sales], 
        Nz(i.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE,0)*Nz(s.quantity,0) AS [COGS],
        Nz(s.SELLING_PRICE * s.quantity,0) - Nz(i.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * s.quantity,0) AS [Sales Margin]                                            
    FROM 
        INVENTORY i
        INNER JOIN SALES_RECEIPT s ON i.INVENTORY_ID = s.INVENTORY_ID
    WHERE DatePart("m",sale_date) = 1
        AND DatePart("yyyy",sale_date) = 2014
    ) a
GROUP BY a.[Sale Month], a.[Sale Year]
ORDER BY a.[Sale Year], a.[Sale Month]
```

Just remove or alter the `WHERE` clause to expand the grouping.

Below is an update based on your questions. You can see how the `WHERE` statement was modified to allow larger ranges. You can also see how the `[Month / Year], [Sale Month],` and `[Sale Year]` columns appear in the `GROUP BY` statement, while the `[Month / Year]` field appears in the `SELECT` statement, and the `[Sale Month],` and `[Sale Year]` fields appear in the `ORDER BY` statement. One is for show, the other two are for it to sort correctly.

```
SELECT a.[Month / Year],        
    ROUND(SUM(a.[Gross Sales]),2) AS [Gross Sales],
    ROUND(SUM(a.[COGS]),2) AS [COGS],
    ROUND(SUM(a.[Sales Margin]),2) AS [Sales Margin],
    Round((Sum(a.[Sales Margin])/Sum([Gross Sales]))/100,2) AS [Profit Margin]    
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        Format(DatePart("m",sale_date),"00") & " / " & DatePart("yyyy",sale_date) AS [Month / Year], 
        Format(DatePart("m",s.sale_date),"00") AS [Sale Month], 
        DatePart("yyyy",s.sale_date) AS [Sale Year], 
        Nz(s.SELLING_PRICE * s.quantity,0) AS [Gross Sales], 
        Nz(i.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE,0)*Nz(s.quantity,0) AS [COGS],
        Nz(s.SELLING_PRICE * s.quantity,0) - Nz(i.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * s.quantity,0) AS [Sales Margin]
    FROM 
        INVENTORY i
        INNER JOIN SALES_RECEIPT s ON i.INVENTORY_ID = s.INVENTORY_ID
    WHERE DatePart("m",sale_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 12
        AND DatePart("yyyy",sale_date) BETWEEN 2014 AND 2016
    ) a
GROUP BY a.[Sale Month], a.[Sale Year], a.[Month / Year]
ORDER BY a.[Sale Year], a.[Sale Month]
```

Comment: I get the error message "Syntax error in FROM clause" and the cursor is  stops on the * in the following line:                                                          Nz(i.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE,0))*s.quantity),0) AS [COGS],

Comment: Looks like I made an error adjusting that field calculation. Looks like it should be 'Nz(i.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE,0)*Nz(s.quantity,0) AS [COGS],' I updated the answer.

Comment: With the updated version, I get the error message "Syntax error in FROM clause" and the cursor stops on the - in the following line:                                                        Nz(s.SELLING_PRICE * s.quantity),0) - Nz(i.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * s.quantity),0) AS [Sales Margin]

Comment: Looks like there were a couple of extra ")"s in there. I removed them and updated my answer. Sorry, I would've caught it if I had a DB set up to run some tests on, which is why I presented my answer as untested. These are simple matters to troubleshoot. The overall structure of the query I presented is correct, and it will get you the results you desire.

Comment: Your code works great.  Could you show me how to modify the code so that it displays all the months (01 thru 12) in the year for a range of years (2009 to 2016).  Is there any way to put the month and year in a single column such as 01/2014?   I added the following to lines to calculate "profit margin" which is the "Sales Margin" divided by the "Gross Sales". With my datebase values 01/2014 should be 74% but it gives that result as 79% indicates something is worng.

Comment: My datebase values for 01/2014 are (Sales Margin $1347), (Gross Sales $1823)  Do you know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: To show all months, remove this 'DatePart("m",sale_date) = 1' (be careful to remove the 'AND' as well). To only show certain months of the year, you can do 'DatePart("m",sale_date) in (1,2,6,7)' (pick your months). To do a range of months, do 'DatePart("m",sale_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 6'. You can similarly choose your years.

Comment: To display the month & year in a column, you can add a [Month / Year] column like what you had. The reason I removed it is that it will not sort correctly. If you have multiple years, it'll lump it the wrong way, like 01/2016, 01/2015, 01/2014, 02/2016, 02/2015, etc. If you add the column for show, then just don't include it in your ORDER BY. I'll update my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Updated. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Looks like your profit margin edit didn't stick. Probably because I was editing at the same time. That's unfortunate. If you add it back, I'll take a look later.

Comment: I see the profit margin now, I don't know if you added it back or if I just missed it before. I do remember the site saying there was an edit that was rejected. Whatevs. 

So, my best guess is that it's dividing gross sales by 100 before dividing the sales margin by the gross sales. In other words, you have MARGIN/GROSS/100, but you should have (MARGIN/GROSS)/100.

Comment: Thank so much for all the help!  I tried executing the lower example and it immediately returns "Overflow" as an error message.  The problem is with this line:                                                                                      ((Nz(s.SELLING_PRICE * s.quantity,0) - Nz(i.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * s.quantity,0)) / (Nz(s.SELLING_PRICE * s.quantity,0))) / 100 AS [Profit Margin]
If I change the first division / to a * the Overflow error goes away but to calculate profit margin I need to do division.  Dividing something by zero would create an overflow error but it's not zero.

Comment: ((Nz(s.SELLING_PRICE * s.quantity,0) - Nz(i.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * s.quantity,0)) / ((s.SELLING_PRICE * s.quantity))) / 100 AS [Profit Margin]     It works if the Nz is removed from the second part of the equation. I didn't have any nulls in the SELLING_PRICE column so I don't know why that's a problem.    $1347.19/$1823.08 = 74% but the result is 79% for Profit Margin.  I think it could be a round error on the Sales Margin.  $1440/$1823 = 79%  I don't know why it would be rounding when the Sales Margin column displays it correctly at $1347.19.

Comment: Another possibility is to handle the division on the outer query. Delete the [Profit Margin] part from the inside query, and put Round((Sum(a.[Sales Margin])/Sum([Gross Sales]))/100,2) AS [Profit Margin] up in the outer part. 

Now that I'm thinking about it, that is a better answer because you'll be aggregating before dividing. Currently, you're doing the calculation record-by-record, ((2/1)/100, (58/65)/100, etc.), which is probably the problem.

Comment: I get the following error message:                                                              Subqueries cannot be used in the expression (Sum(Round(,2))).                     The problem line is:   Round((Sum(a.[Sales Margin])/Sum([Gross Sales]))/100,2) AS [Profit Margin]                                                                                               If I remove the division as follows there's no error:  Round((Sum(a.[Sales Margin]))/100,2) AS [Profit Margin]    but I need to do division to find the percent profit.

Comment: That's unexpected. I was just playing with a similar query geared for a dataset I have on hand, and I couldn't replicate the problem. Try adding another set of () around ((Sum(a.[Sales Margin])/Sum([Gross Sales]))/100). Another thought is to try it like (([Gross]-[COGS])/[Gross])/100. Or just do it without the ROUND, and handle that bit of formatting in whatever reporting program or module you have this exporting to.

Comment: The following works!!   Round([Sales Margin]/[Gross Sales],2) AS [Profit Margin]    I would also like to create another query with the same calculations but for each day for numerous years.   The key changes I made are:  SELECT a.[Month / Day / Year],

Comment: Format(DatePart("m",sale_date),"00") & " / " & DatePart("d",sale_date),"00")  & " / " & DatePart("yyyy",sale_date) AS [Month / Day / Year], 
 Format(DatePart("d",s.sale_date),"00") AS [Sale Day],
        Format(DatePart("m",s.sale_date),"00") AS [Sale Month], 
        DatePart("yyyy",s.sale_date) AS [Sale Year],                                                                                                                            DatePart("m",sale_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 12
AND DatePart("d",sale_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 31
AND DatePart("yyyy",sale_date) BETWEEN 2014 AND 2016

Comment: GROUP BY a.[Sale Month], a.[Sale Day], a.[Sale Year], a.[Month / Day / Year]
ORDER BY a.[Sale Year], a.[Sale Month], a.[Sale Day]                                   This results in an error. The cursor stops on the first & in this part of the code  .....DatePart("d",sale_date),"00")  & " / " & DatePart("yyyy",.........

Comment: `& DatePart("d",sale_date),"00") &` That needs to either have `FORMAT(` added or `,"00")` taken off. Based on your choice later on, I'm guessing you want it like this: `& Format(DatePart("d",sale_date),"00") &`

Comment: oh, hey, since my answer helped out, can you mark it as the accepted answer? I'd really appreciate that!

Comment: Your answer: & Format(DatePart("d",sale_date),"00") & solved the problem so both the monthly and the daily aggregate calculations queries work great!!  Thank you so much!!