# Is 'between' which includes START and END date?

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to query 10 days data from snowflake database. I tried the date between '2019-07-30' and '2019-08-09' which includes start and end date?

Comment: Yes it includes start and end date and you could easily find this in the documentation.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the dates contain times too, then no! Then the end date might be excluded.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you are asking about, may or may not be a Possible duplicate of [T-SQL Between Dates Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5434001/11683)

Comment: *"I have to query 10 days data from snowflake database"* Well edited and rollback the tags as i was thinking at first the topicstarter was using [snowflake RDMS](https://www.snowflake.com/) instead of the snowflake schema

Comment: Yes, @RaymondNijland I am using Snowflake.

Comment: `expr BETWEEN lower_bound AND upper_bound` is equivalent to `expr >= lower_bound AND expr <= upper_bound`  see [manual](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/between.html)

Answer (score 5):

Dates should be in single quotes as such:

```
Date >= '2019-07-30' and Date <= '2019-08-09'
```

You can also use between as you mentioned:

```
Date between '2019-07-30' and '2019-08-09'
```

Adding this into your WHERE clause will seperate results between these two dates

Comment: Your second query actually may include _eleven_, not ten, calendar days.

Comment: Yes. My query like this "between '2019-07-30' and '2019-08-09'" which means 11 days?

Comment: I am querying from snowflake database.

Comment: As there is no time defined, SQL server defaults the time to 00:00:00, so it would, in reality, be 30th July 2019 00:00:00 to 09th August 2019 00:00:00

Answer (score 5):

If you want to include all dates including today going back 9 days (so 10 total days) then try using this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE date >= DATEADD(DAY, -9, CURRENT_DATE()) AND
      date <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, CURRENT_DATE())
```

This says to match dates which occur on or after midnight of 9 days ago, up until any date strictly before midnight of tomorrow (implying all of today matches).

Answer (score 5):

Here's the [BETWEEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/between.html#collation-details) Snowflake documentation, and it reads:

"The expression A BETWEEN X AND Y is equivalent to A >= X AND A <= Y"

Answer (score 0):

### use below Query

SELECT * FROM snowflake WHERE start_date >='2019-07-30' and end_date <= '2019-08-09';