# Microsoft SQL Server : I need my date to be selected as date, however, I need to append 00:00:00 to start @StartDate and 23:59:59 to at end date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am declaring Date and I need to keep it as date and not datetime.

```
DECLARE @StartDate Date = '2022-01-01'
```

I think set that date to a local date variable.

```
DECLARE @LocalStartDate Date = @StartDate
```

I want to be able to add time to the end of `@StartDate`.

I can't use + '00:00:00' at the end of that declare.

I can do it else where in code but I was wondering if there is a way to do it in this second declare.

Comment: It's either a date or a datetime. It's not a date with a time. If you want time, then you need datetime.

Comment: As an aside, using a boundary like `23:59:59` (inclusive) for a time range is asking for trouble (what about events occurring in the final second of the day?) Exclusive ranges are typically easier to work with and reason about (so `< '2022-01-02'` and not `<= '2022-01-01 23:59:59'`). As a bonus, this might allow you to stick with dates.

Comment: I don't want time, however, when I was searching for data between two dates it was cutting off some information that was done late at night for some reason. The data has a time attached and we found that when adding in the time it did not cutt off the data that entered late. (Before 12am.) @JeroenMostert I don't believe I can use > in a declare. Am I missing something?

Comment: `Am I missing something?` - you should use the `>` in a `select`, not in a `declare`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T-SQL Between Dates Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434001/t-sql-between-dates-confusion)

Comment: Thank you! I was just wanting to know if possible and your answered helped!